# When I set an element to be visible is there a delay between then and the time I can check the element's width?

Tags: angularjs

If I have:

```
<div id="abc" data-ng-show="abc.visible">xxx</div>
```

and in javascript:

```
$scope.abc.visible = true;
var modal = document.getElementById('abc');
var modal_width = parseInt(modal.width, 10)
var modal_height = parseInt(modal.height, 10)
var abc = $('#abc').width();
```

How can I now get the width of the div straight after setting the visible to true? I tried the above but it does not seem to be available to me.

Note that modal.width and modal.height both show here as undefined

Comment: Yes you should be able to get the height. What response do you get when getting the width?

Comment: how did you try to access the width?

Comment: I updated the question to answer both comments. When I look at the variable in the debugger with Google Chrome I don't see anything there that gives me a width or height other than 0's or undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a delay. You need to watch $scope.abc.visible for changes. I've created a plunker to show you what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/zmPPcHVkc6RbdQvYRBtX?p=preview.